In Vorpal.js Auto complete will not work in option to search the file names
I like the some features in vorpal like Custom Delimiter, Banner and handling command and options. But auto-complete will not work for option to search the filesystem.
Eg:

Vorpal$ open -f ../[file-system]

Auto complete will not work to find the file system.
